# Unable to install the <em class="placeholder">lightning</em> module since it does not exist

Tags: drupal-8

When I tried to install Acquia BLT project (Command: blt setup), I am getting the below error in the console.

```
[error]  Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors validating the config synchronization.
Site UUID in source storage does not match the target storage.
Unable to install the <em class="placeholder">lightning</em> module since it does not exist. 
in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate() (line 737 of 
/var/www/cmap/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php).

In ConfigImportCommands.php line 259:

The import failed due to the following reasons:
Site UUID in source storage does not match the target storage.
Unable to install the <em class="placeholder">lightning</em> module since it does not exist.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are using Drupal VM for BLT project. This error will occur due to the missing of composer libraries. Please run the below commands in your terminal.

```
rm -rf docroot/modules/contrib
composer install
vagrant ssh
[now inside the VM]
blt setup
```

Comment: I have also removed vendor folder and lock file, it works fine. Thank you.